# Moving props data to state to generate forms

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm planning to add a prefilled form with React. I have the actual data on props. This is what I came up with.

```
@connect(...)
class Some extends React.Component {
   state = {
      ...this.props.auth.user
   }

   render() {
     // Create a form using the data on state
   }
}
```

It looks not correct since I'm not using a react lifecycle hook here. I would like to ask if there is a better practice to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but can't you just send the props directly to the form? As in each input value set the `this.props.value` as the attribute value?

Comment: Generally its good practice to set the form values directly from the props. And then having an `onChange` event to set the state to whatever gets edited after. No need for lifecycle events.

Comment: you can add it in the value like so: `this.state.value ?? this.props.value`. This will prevent the props from overriding your state when you have later editions :)

Comment: @RafaelRocha So you want me to pass something like <input value={this.props.something} and use onChange event which changes the state? If that's the case, I won't be able to type anything on input because props will never change. Maybe I misunderstood you here.

Comment: Like the comment below someone has to control that component. If you place in the input something like this:

Comment: Added a more elaborate answer below, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to elaborate on my previous responses you would do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
@connect(...)
class Some extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
   }
}
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} id="some" type="text" value= {this.state.value|| this.props.value}/>
        </div>
     )
   }
}
```

While your value is an empty string (in the state), the fields will be populated from your props and as soon as you start typing it will overwrite the prepopulated values with the ones in your state.

**Best practices would be to actually have a Component that handles this logic and then passes the props to the form that should be just a dumb presentational component:**

```
class SomeController extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    }
 }
 handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  return (<Form handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />)
}
```

And then your form component:

```
const Form = (props) => (
  <form>
    <input onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.value} />
  </form>
);
```

Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your architecture,since you are using uncontrolled component here, it is  recommended to keep the source of truth at one place.

you can do something like this:

```
@connect(...)
class Some extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName:this.props.auth.user
   }
}
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({userName: event.target.value});
  }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} id="some" type="text" value= {this.state.userName}/>
        </div>
     )
   }
}
```

If you want to use controlled component that is controlled through parent/container. you can manage the values through props and set the props onChange.

Comment: Also like I mentioned in the comments above you can just `this.state.value || this.props.value` in the input value attributes. Letting it be pre populated when you don't have any interaction with state at first.

Comment: @RafaelRocha it will not behave well when user is clearing the value. Thats the whole idea of initializing in constructor, it ll not render without initializing.